# Como consumir un método GET desde .NET (C#), cuando requiere in Id en la URL y un token en el Body?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Como puedo consumir un método GET desde .NET (C#), cuando dicho método requiere in Id en la URL y un token en el Body.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido @user187916 te invitamos a visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). deberas crear un nuevo objeto `RestClient` donde agregas la url de tu `api` y un objeto `RestRequest` en el cual le pasas el metodo `GET`.

Ejemplo:

```
string url = String.Format("https://url/api/{0}", Id);
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("content-type", contentType);//"application/json");
request.AddHeader("X-Access-Token",token);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var result = response.Content;
HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola pues lo puedes consumir utilizando las librerías de `System.Net.WebClient`
o PostMan te da la facilidad utilizando el nugget de *RestSharp* generar el código para invocar tu petición para.Net C#
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]